# C# Observer pattern EntityState

Tags: c#, observer-pattern

Ok from the start. I have a MVC EF application (a website). People can make orders on that website. When all the orders are made for the day, one person (shopper) opens the front end app (made with react) and this loads via an API call all the ordered products. So far so good. I made a button in the frontend app named "unavailable". When the shopper clicks on it, it activates a methode in the MVC app the send a mail to the user who made an order to change the product to an other one. So far so good. 
The person clicks the link in the mail, goes to the website and changes the specific product to a new one. 
Now this new products has to be updated in the frontend app so what I wanted to do is when the button is clicked, do long polling to an api url and wait for the server (website) to respond with the new product.

I have html form (the form where the user changes the product) and when the user clicks submit, some records get modified in the database.

This is de code (found in the `OrderController`):

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ChangeOrder(int orderId, int productId)
    {
        //get huidige order
        var order = _db.Orders.Where(o => o.OrderId == orderId).SingleOrDefault();
        //get prijs van het nieuwe product
        var productPrice = _db.Products.Where(p => p.ProductId == productId).SingleOrDefault();
        //pas prijs aan in de order
        order.UnitPrice = productPrice.Details.PriceLabelNow;
        //pas product id aan in de order
        order.ProductId = productId;
        order.Date = DateTime.Now;
        //update de database
        _db.setOrderModified(order);
        _db.SaveChanges();

        return View("OrderChanged");
    }
```

This is how setOrderModified looks like (its found in my Context class):

```
    public void setOrderModified (object entity)
    {
        Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
```

Now I want to use the Observer Pattern to monitor `ChangeOrder` so its sends a sigal to an other methode when my form is submitted.

I was thinking of makeing `setORderMoified` as a Subject, but I have no idea how to do that.

Since the comments suggested an eventhandler I add the code which has to evoked when the form is submitted.

This is the api call which the frontend uses to get the new product.

```
 // GET /api/orders/one/{device_id}/{id}/{date}
    [HttpGet]
    [ActionName("one")]
    public OrdersAPI GetOrder(string device_id, int id, string date)
    {

        //fire this when the form is submitted.
         var result = repository.GetUpdated(device_id, id, date);
        return result;

    }
```

Anyone who can help me out or have a better idea?

Comment: You could create event and notify all subscribers,

Comment: It looks like `EntityFramework` but there is no mention of in the question. Which ORM (and which version) are you using?

Comment: @valheru To me it's not clear what do you want to achieve. I would suggest you to edit your question. `sends a sigal to an other methode when my form is submitted.` is one thing and the general `Implement the Observer Pattern` is a lot different and we can only guess what is the actual goal we want to achieve. If a simple event could do it I don't see why you would need to observe the properties.

Comment: @MatanShahar Yes I am using EF. Leron Your right, it looks like an event can handle this task as well. I add the part what the event has to evoke.

Comment: @valheru It's even less clear now what you are trying to achieve. I don't want to spam your question but just two things. If I read your question literally then calling `repository.GetUpdated(device_id, id, date);` inside `ChangeOrder(..)` should be sufficient. But judging from the code I suspect that after the form is submitted you have some Ajax on the FE which updates the data for the user. I may not be right, but at least for me it is very unclear what is the real problem here.

Comment: @Leron thanks for your reply. I added some extra info to my startpost. Hope this helps to make things clearer

Comment: @valheru I'm afraid you'll have to put a little more effort into this. I would suggest you to rethink what exactly you want to do and ask another question, which is specific for the approach you chose. Possible options to achieve what you want is 1 - in `ChangeOrder` when you `return View("OrderChanged");` to pass a model as well which will require some additional changes. 2 - Make some sort of Ajax call instead of form submit... maybe there are other options too, but this question is too broad to get an answer I think.